# Simple dice game, error message

Tags: c++, syntax, dice

I am trying to build a really simple first game with simulated dice rolls.

I am getting an error on line 49: `if(rollResult>aiRollResult)`.

I'm sure it's just a really simple syntax error with all the `if` statements but I cannot figure out how to fix it or can I not call the `airoll()` function in the middle of my code like I did?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void airoll();

int main() {
    int b;
    srand(time(0));
    //random die roll
    int rollResult = 1+(rand()%6);

    switch (rollResult) //results options {
        case 1: {
            cout<<"Your Roll: 1"<<endl;
        }
        break;
        case 2: {
            cout<<"Your Roll: 2"<<endl;
        }
        break;
        case 3: {
            cout<<"Your Roll: 3"<<endl;
        }
        break;
        case 4: {
            cout<<"Your Roll: 4"<<endl;
        }
        break;
        case 5: {
            cout<<"Your Roll: 5"<<endl;
        }
        break;
        case 6: {
            cout<<"Your Roll: 6"<<endl;
        }
        break;
    }

    airoll();

    if(rollResult>aiRollResult) {
        cout<<"You win!"<<endl;
    }

    if (aiRollResult>rollResult) {
        cout<<"You lose!"<<endl;
    }

    if (rollResult==aiRollResult) {
        cout<<"It's a tie!"<<endl;
    }
}

void airoll() {
    int aiRollResult=1+(rand()%6);
    cout<<"AI roll: "<<aiRollResult<<endl;
}
```

Comment: That formatting/indentation should really be revised. The code is hard to read.

Comment: "An error"? Which one? If it is "Undefined variable: aiRollResult", can you figure out why?

Comment: Also, your switch syntax is strange - you don't need to create a block (with { and }) after each `case`.

Comment: `cout<<"Your Roll: " << rollResult <<endl;` does the same thing as your entire switch block.

Comment: Prefer the `<random>` header.

Comment: *"I am getting an error on line 49"*  You were so darn close to asking a good question, then ***FAIL***.  You know you got an error... you even know which line its on.  **Why wouldn't you share the *exact error message* with the people you're asking for help?**

Comment: i do not see an exact message nor do i know how to view it i am clearly new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `aiRollResult` is not defined in the scope of the `main()` function. It only exists in the scope of the `airoll()` function.
Change your `airoll()` to

```
int airoll()
{
    int aiRollResult=1+(rand()%6);
    cout<<"AI roll: "<<aiRollResult<<endl;
    return aiRollResult;
}
```

Notice the `int` return type.

Now you can get the result of the `airoll()` in the main function as follows:

```
int aiRollResult = airoll();
```

Which will call the `airoll()` function and then store the result in the variable. That should solve your problem.
Learn more about functions here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/

Comment: @joe It is good practice here on SO to accept the answer that solved your problem so mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You've to declare and initialize a variable named `aiRollResult` which would be from the function `airoll()`. So change the function from returning `void` to returning `int`. Decouple the message display; show it in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

The `aiRollResult` variable inside the function:

```
void airoll() {
    int aiRollResult=1+(rand()%6);
    cout<<"AI roll: "<<aiRollResult<<endl;
}
```

is a local variable to the function. It means that when the function has done running, the integer is deallocated. I'd suggest you to return the integer instead:

```
int airoll() {
    int aiRollResult=1+(rand()%6);
    cout<<"AI roll: "<<aiRollResult<<endl;
    return aiRollResult;
}
```

Now you can replace:

```
airoll();
```

with:

```
int aiRollResult = airoll();
```

and you are set.

I've also noticed that in the switch statements you are doing:

```
    case 1: {
        cout<<"Your Roll: 1"<<endl;
    }
    break;
```

The enclosing brackets are not required at all. With those brackets you are creating an inner block of code., which is only useful if you are declaring a variable within the `case` statement.

You can rewrite those lines as:

```
case 1: cout << "Your Roll: 1" << endl; break;
```

Finally, don't pollute the current namespace with:

```
using namespace std;
```

get used to use the `std::` prefix or include what you really need with:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple. The `aiRollResult` variable is a local variable which can't be seen outside of its function's brackets

To solve this you can declare a global variable and initialize it to the `aiRollResult` value

Comment: Introducing a global variable is not really a *good* solution. "To solve it", the OP might as well move the AIroll code into his main -- after all, it's only used once.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, I see:

```
switch (rollResult) //results options {
    [.. bunch of case statements...]
}

airoll();
```

Notice that the opening `{` of the `switch` statement is hidden by a `//` comment.

But you still have the closing `}`.

**I think you have mismatched braces.**

The final brace, which you think is closing your switch statement, is actually closing main. Then the `airoll();` is a function call outside any function, causing an error.

Others have described the scoping problem of `aiRollResult`, but I don't think that is the direct cause of the error you're describing.

(of course, if you had posted the ***exact error message*** in your original question, we could be more helpful)

Comment: Well spotted nevertheless. As the other posters must've done, I eyeballed whereabout line 49 would be -- ignoring all previous experience where the compiler would report an error on line *x* where the *fault* is actually on line *x-y* (where *y* is always larger than you think).

Answer (score 0):

To sum up everything that's been said, but nobody has actually said all at once:

```
    switch (rollResult) //results options {
```

This is causing a mismatched brace. Put your brace before the comment, like this:

```
    switch (rollResult) { // results options
```

While this is technically correct, it sucks:

```
    case 1: {
        cout<<"Your Roll: 1"<<endl;
    }
    break;
```

Change it to this:

```
    case 1:
        cout<<"Your Roll: 1"<<endl;
        break;
```

This doesn't do anything useful for the if statements that follow:

```
    airoll();
```

Make it look like this:

```
    aiRollResult = airoll();
```

Of course, that means that you'll have to declare aiRollResult up above in your declarations section.

Finally, this function prints a value, but you can't use the value, because it immediately throws that value straight into the trash can:

```
    void airoll() {
        int aiRollResult=1+(rand()%6);
        cout<<"AI roll: "<<aiRollResult<<endl;
    }
```

Make it look like this:

```
    int airoll() {
        int aiRollResult = 1 + (rand() % 6);
        cout << "AI roll: " << aiRollResult << endl;
        return aiRollResult;
    }
```

Also, the comment about namespace pollution might be taken into account, but let's not get into a coding style fight, eh?

Comment: I did forget to mention....using white space is a good thing for readability, and it will help you debug. Use it liberally, but come up with a scheme. I personally use the linux kernel coding style and the doxygen commenting style.

Comment: hm okay ill look into that